# IOS - UIButton text align left Equal the text of another UIButton contains image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I am new in IOS. I want to know how to make the text in `UIButton` align left equal the text of another `UIButton` that contains an image.
Which flexible way to achieve it? (I mean flexible way here is when I change the size of the image the text align still correct)
Can I do it by config UI only or I need to code?
Here is the image description

[image: Here is the image description]

Comment: You have tried by setting Title Edge inset of button?

Comment: @Jaimish, Yes I tried it but it is still not very good. If I set the Title Edge inset LEFT of button1 is 10 and button2 is 10 too, the align is not correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As both the image and the text are part of the `UIButton` and hidden in interface builder, this is a bit tricky to achieve.

Some ways to do it:

1) Add an empty image with the same width to the second button, and keep those two images the same width.

2) Play with the title insets on the second button to move the text to the right position. The title insets will be related to the image width.

3) Don't make the text part of the button, but set it as `UILabel` on top of it.

**Disadvantage**: You won't get the button changes in your text (different color on press for example).

**Advantage**: Constraints can be used easily, and you get all benefits of `UILabel`s like multiline and so on.

Comment: If no more easy way to do it. I prefer the way 1, it easy to setup the UI and also when I need to handle the event. Thank you so much for your explain.

Comment: I personally go with option 3 nowadays, there's so much the `UIButton` title label can't do easily out of the box ...

Comment: Thank you for your best suggestion. I will consider it

Answer (score 1):

I think it may help you

```
CGFloat Imagewidth = 10; // width of the image you need to set 
firstButtonBtn.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, Imagewidth);
seconbutton.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, Imagewidth, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I choosed the way 1 of TheEye answer because rightnow I think it will be better if I can do it by config UI only then I will have less code. Thank you so much for your time and your solution